# how to map a dynamic json key to a object for a post request in java

Tags: json, dynamic, http-post

I have some json that i want to parse into pojo

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
123:[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
```

here 123 is a numeric key which is dynamic some one can please tell me how to create a pojo which handles this dynamic key

Answer (score 0):

one question: doesn't this dynamic key need to be convert to pojo?